# Unity3D: How can I make the camera rotate around an object, with an angle on the camera, only on x-axis, by right-mousebutton drag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am making a game in Unity3D, I'm stuck because I want to make the Main camera, being able to be dragged with right-mousebutton.

I have already tried some codes that fundamentally work, but the "Orbit" rotation is doing the rotation relative to the rotation of the camera itself.

So what I want to, is to make the camera rotate around an object, on right-mousebutton drag, while the camera is looking down on the object, and still is able to rotate around the object, with a linear orbit?

How can I do this? need help for real!

Comment: This question surely has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the camera to an empty game object by making it a child and rotate that instead. You can then place your camera anywhere in the scene at any rotation and when you rotate the parent object, it will orbit that point.

Comment: Thank You so freakin' much, It Worked!!!